# Is using Dependency Resolver a bad practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am going to make up an example here just to get my point across. Please consider the following class:

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMovieService _movieService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public MovieController(IMovieService movieService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _movieService = movieService;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public ViewModel GetMovies()
    {
        return View("Movies", _movieService.GetMovies());
    }

    public ViewModel GetAuthors()
    {
        return View("Authors", _userService.GetAuthors());
    }
}
```

With the example above, whenever the MovieController is created, it will create both services. Each service will require its services and repositories in the constructor. So, in reality, I may be creating some classes each time MovieController is called. For this reason, I want to implement Lazy loading as I believe it will improve performance. For this reason, please consider the next class:

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMovieService _movieService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    private MovieService 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_movieService == null) _movieService = new MovieService();
            return _movieService;
        }
    }

    private UserService 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_userService == null) _userService = new UserService();
            return _userService;
        }
    }

    public MovieController() { }

    public ViewModel GetMovies()
    {
        return View("Movies", MovieService.GetMovies());
    }

    public ViewModel GetAuthors()
    {
        return View("Authors", UserService.GetAuthors());
    }
}
```

The problem with the above example is that I lost DI. Now I understand the benefit of DI, and I very much want to keep it, and as such, I came up with the following example:

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMovieService _movieService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    private MovieService 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_movieService == null) _movieService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IMovieService));
            return _movieService;
        }
    }

    private UserService 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_userService == null) _userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUserService));
            return _userService;
        }
    }

    public MovieController() { }

    public ViewModel GetMovies()
    {
        return View("Movies", MovieService.GetMovies());
    }

    public ViewModel GetAuthors()
    {
        return View("Authors", UserService.GetAuthors());
    }
}
```

Is my third example in this question a bad practice? If so, why? Am I losing on performance by doing this or is there another reason why this would be considered bad practice?

Comment: In regards to the third approach one question that pops in my head right away is how do I `unit` test "GetMovies"

Comment: Why would you even care to check if _userService/_movieService are null? You never use them twice

Comment: @Jaya I think I see your point, you are asking me how to be able to pass a fake DbContext vs a real one.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Completely beside the point and out of scope for the question. It's just a sample code.

Comment: Without the constructor of both MovieService and UserService, we can't answer this. Why is it that they are so expensive to instantiate that you don't want to do it when not needed?

Comment: @here why the downvote. @Bojan : right, fake anything in this case a `Mocked<IUserService>` and `Mocked<IMovieService>` basically to test various scenarios : like how do you test return type/result , how do you test any forked logic inside the `GetMovies` if any based on the obtained result etc (just making up these scenarios)

Comment: By the way, if you need to resolve the dependency yourself (third case), you also lost DI

Comment: @Jaya I could also inject into my unit tests to ensure testing is possible. Never really done that, but now I am wondering if it is such bad idea?

Comment: @Bojan came across this article the other day that you may find interesting https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-core-lazy-command-pattern/

Comment: @Nkosi that was a good read. Thank you. Its what Yacoub Massad suggested just more in depth.

Comment: @Bojan as soon as I saw your question it reminded me about that article. Yes Yacoub's answers landed relatively close to what was done in the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the dependency resolver this way means that you are using [the service locator anti-pattern](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/10/25/object-composability-another-reason-why-the-service-locator-is-an-anti-pattern/).

Is there any reason why you think that creating `MovieService` and `UserService` will have performance issues? Are you doing something significant in the constructor of these classes? If so, then you probably shouldn't. In the constructor you should almost always just accept the dependencies and store them in private fields.

If for some reason, you still want lazy loading, then you can create something like this:

```
public class LazyMovieService : IMovieService
{
    private readonly Lazy<IMovieService> lazyInstance;

    public LazyMovieService(Func<IMovieService> instanceFactory)
    {
        lazyInstance = new Lazy<IMovieService>(instanceFactory);
    }
    public string[] GetMovies()
    {
        return lazyInstance.Value.GetMovies();
    }
}
```

This class allows you to use the first code example in your code while still being able to lazily load your services.

In the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), you would simply do something like:

```
var controller =
    new MovieController(
        new LazyMovieService(() => new MyOriginalMovieService(...)),
        ...);
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure the last part applies here (the composition root part) since it seems to be an ASP.NET Core DI (i.e you don't instantiate the Controller). But I also asked about the performance problem of instantiating the services

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: not only it doesn't apply here but also it wouldn't apply to original mvc as well. You don't instantiate controllers by your own there also.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, in ASP.NET MVC, you can create a custom `IControllerFactory`, this is how you do [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I remember there is a way to use Pure DI in ASP.NET Core too.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, you can do it probably by implementing `IControllerActivator`, `IViewComponentActivator` and `ITagHelperActivator`

Comment: @YacoubMassad: you could but you don't really need it, only the last part of your answer is unnecessary, the rest is ok. You just inject lazies and that's all. I won't even bother finishing my own answer here as yours covers the issue.

Comment: I'd think that's too much trouble for no real benefit, but I might be missing something.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'd say the real answer is to check the services initialization code, since even implementing this lazy-ness won't help a lot

Comment: @WiktorZychla, I use Pure DI for a reason, see this article for more details: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1285/clean-composition-roots-dependency-injection

Comment: In another article [here](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/), I describe some problems of using DI containers.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, see the articles I send in the comments for the reason why I use Pure DI.

Comment: @YacoubMassad what do you think about this article I came across the other day https://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-core-lazy-command-pattern/

Comment: @Nkosi, I think it is a good article. I only use ASP.NET lightly. But more and more I think that concept of a controller should be removed. As this article shows, the only role of the controller is to enable routing to some command/query handler. I bet someone can create a library that enables developers to route to command/query handlers directly.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: remember that controllers have access to all the infrastructure info (http context, route datas etc) while handlers barely do so, they onoy implement specific logic. When there are no controllers how would you glue the http context stuff directly to handlers? Even if technically possible, that doesn't sound right from the OO perspective.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, you can access such infrastructure info via dependencies. Regarding OO, no one really knows what OO is really about. I have seen very different opinions of what OO is about. Is it about data encapsulation? or polymorphism? Or about modeling real-world things? etc.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: following SOLID/GRASP for example. Injecting infrastructure-specific dependencies to service classes sounds wrong, services should be infrastructure-agnostic otherwise you break the SRP. Anyway, this "someone" to provide a different approach could be you, make a proof-of-concept of a small framework and let people comment it. You even got your first feedback, from me, without even writing a single line of code ;) Regards.